# Google chart not rendering - cannot add ticks

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm having a lot of trouble with the google charts, they just stopped working recently. I did a lot of configuring and almost solved it but the ticks do not appear unless they are manually set and whenever I try to delete thicks line it throws me one of these errors:

And I only get this error in safari:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.rb.min')

or this with chrome:

> Cannot read property 'min' of undefined×

I get the same errors with even the google example:

```
      var options = {
          title: "Traffic Visits",
          isStacked: 'false',
          height: 340,
          pointSize: 3,
          lineWidth: 1,
          legend: {position: 'top', maxLines: 3},
          vAxis: {
              title: "traffic Views",
              minValue: 0,
              ticks: "auto",
              titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}
          }
      };
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What chart are you using?
Are you loading version "1" or "1.1" ?
(in your `google.load('visualization', '(1 or 1.1)', {'packages':['corechart']});`?

Comment: yes, tried both 1 and 1.1 :(

Comment: Could you make a small fiddle mimicking your problem?